# How to Uninstall Neo4j from Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: neo4j, uninstallation

How to install Neo4j from a Ubuntu 13.04 system

I tried under root privilege "apt-get remove neo4j"...

But it didn't work, I can still see neo4j package in my '/etc' folder.

What should I do to uninstall Neo4j from my system?

Comment: Don't forget to remove `/var/lib/neo4j/`

Answer (score 11):

try `apt-get purge neo4j` to get rid of it

Comment: `sudo apt-get purge neo4j*` just to be sure. And then, `sudo apt-get autoremove` also.

Answer (score 9):

To remove completely

1. For community edition

   sudo apt-get purge neo4j
2. For enterprise edition

   sudo apt-get purge neo4j-enterprise

Answer (score 5):

For **community version**:

```
sudo apt-get purge neo4j
```

For **enterprise version**:

```
sudo apt-get purge neo4j-enterprise
```

Answer (score 3):

After deleting neo4j you might want to check data folder, on my Ubuntu it was in /var/lib/neo4j/data/. 
I have been working with 68Gb datasets and removing those helped to get lots of disk space back.

Answer (score 2):

For the community version of Neo4j 4.3 on Ubuntu, I found that I needed all the steps below to completely uninstall everything (assuming you're trying to obliterate everything, and not saving anything!):

1. sudo apt-get purge neo4j
2. sudo rm -r /var/lib/neo4j/*
3. sudo rmdir /var/lib/neo4j/
4. sudo apt autoremove  (gets rid of cypher-shell daemon)

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [here](https://github.com/neo4j-devtools/neo4j-desktop/issues/77):

> If you downloaded the AppImage, to uninstall you need to remove the
> following items:
>
> (1) The downloaded AppImage: this is the executable used to run Neo4j
> Desktop. 
> (2) The ~/.config/Neo4j Desktop directory: this is where Neo4j
> Desktop stores configuration files, databases, apps, plugins, and some
> other files. 
> (3) The
> ~/.local/share/applications/appimagekit-neo4j-desktop-[version].AppImage
> file: this is a *.desktop entry, a file used by most desktop
> environments to list installed applications. To refresh the content of
> your application menu after deleting or making changes to this
> *.desktop entries you can run sudo update-desktop-database (this is a system command, it's unrelated to Neo4j Desktop) or reboot.

I did not have to do (3) as it was not there.